# how can i save array to another array in for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, telegram-bot

In for loop I wanna use send message method (telegram bot).

Few times ($arrlength) with just one time with text (not few times, always 1 time).

For example this for loop maybe repeat 20 times and I want to send message 20 times and 1 time text, but my above code sending message with text few times! Then I think I should get out my send message method from for loop and save all indexes array in another array.

For example : This for loop repeat 3 times and I wanna save all 3 indexes in another array then use send message method out of for loop

```
 //var : 
$saves =array();
$saves_id =array(); 
$saveus = array(); 

$resultt  = $conn->query("SELECT performer,file_id,title FROM databasebot 
 WHERE performer = '$message' or title = '$message'");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($resultt))
{
// array title
      $saves[] = $row[2];
      //array file_id
      $saves_id[] = $row[1];


}
 $arrlength = count($saves);

   for($x = 0; $x <= $arrlength; $x++) {

    $poets['keyboard'][] = array($saves[$x]);

 $jsonPoets= json_encode($poets);
  //send message method ... !
 // chat_id , text , reply_markup are required in sendmessage method

 $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?
 chat_id=".$chat_id."&text= choose song : "."&reply_markup=".$jsonPoets;

   file_get_contents($url);
 }
```

maybe i can do like this :

```
  for($x = 0; $x <= $arrlength; $x++) {

        $poets['keyboard'][] = array($saves[$x]);

// this in not working ... !
        $saveus[$x][] = $poets[$x] +$saveus[$x];        

}        

 $jsonPoets= json_encode($saveus);
$text= "song : ";
$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?
chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$text."&reply_markup=".$jsonPoets;
    file_get_contents($url);
```

what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand from your question, you want to send a message to Telegram only once whilst sending results from multiple for loops.

Try this code:

```
$poets = array(

    "keyboard" => array()

);

for($x = 0; $x <= $arrlength; $x++) {


    $poets['keyboard'][] = array($saves[$x]);


}     

$jsonPoets= json_encode($poets);
//send message method ... !
// chat_id , text , reply_markup are required in sendmessage method

$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?
chat_id=".$chat_id."&text= choose song : "."&reply_markup=".$jsonPoets;

file_get_contents($url);
```